# How does data binding with DOM element work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering, how jquery can associate arbitrary data with any DOM element without adding any HTML data attribute?

```
$('#div_id').data('suffix',(count++)) ;
```

I don't see any data attribute associate with HTML element in firebug HTML snapshot.

What is the mechanism?

Although this data storage method is no longer needed in HTML5, still i am not clear actual mechanism of jquery data storage.

Comment: Maybe it maintains an internal hash or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It adds a property to the element which contains a number value that represents an index in the `jQuery.cache` object like so:

```
$('#footer').data('suffix',"suffix");
jQuery.cache[ $('#footer')[0][jQuery.expando] ].suffix;
//"suffix"
```

I used `"#footer"` because I ran the code on this page. Note that the object structure for `jQuery.cache[index]` will be different on elements that also have events bound to them by jQuery.

You should never touch it in code anyway so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks Esailija for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery adds a property to the DOM element which is the key it uses to look things up in an internal hash.

If you inspect the DOM element in firebug or something after you've associated data with it you'll see the jQueryxxxxxxxx property